# Python: Raw_Input inside an if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I'm starting out at python. I keep getting an error when I put a new raw_input inside an if statement. If the input they answered is incorrect I want to give them another chance to enter more input, is there another way to do this?

Heres the Code

```
attraction = {
    'approach' : "words",
    'introduction' : "words",
    'qualification' : "words",
    'rapport' : "words"
}

answer = raw_input("Pick from these approaches: introduction, qualification, or rapport:")

if answer != "approach" and answer != "introduction" and answer != "qualification" and answer != "rapport":
    new_answer = raw_input("You didn't choose one of the choices, type in the choice you want again:")
if new_answer != "approach" and answer != "introduction" and answer != "qualification" and answer != "rapport":
    print "That was your last chance buddy"
else:
    print attraction[answer]
```

Comment: put the raw input in a while loop.  Use break when you have an answer

Comment: I know this is not a related question, but, may I ask why did you start out learning Python 2.7? Why not Python 3?

Comment: Not related to your question: it's easier to write: `if answer not in ("approach", "introduction", "qualification", "rapport"):`

Comment: I think you should use `or` expression instead of `and' because single input can't be of 3 different type.

Comment: You can also do `if answer not in attraction.keys():`

Comment: @Kira I literally started learning yesterday on codeacademy the only other experience I have is Java two year ago as a senior in highschool,so to answer your question simply, I have no idea. and thanks for all the feedback people!

Comment: The problem is that the `else` will be executed only if the first `if` is not true. So in case the user entered "wrong" input and got to the second `if` - the `else` part won't get printed even if the user entered a valid input on the second time.

Comment: Cool!, well be aware that, CPython has two major implementations, Python 2.x and Python 3.x. Something that works in Python 2.x may not work in Python 3.x and vise versa. For instance `raw_input()` it's now `input()` in Pyton 3.x and `input()` it's something different in Python 2.x.

Comment: You prompt for three options but have 4 in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make a new variable `new_answer` when you're asking them the second time, you can just set `answer` to a new value:

```
answer = raw_input("You didn't choose one of the choices, type in the choice you want again:")
```

And replace `new_answer` with `answer` elsewhere in your program.

I would do the program like this, using the `.keys()` method:

```
attraction = {
    'approach' : "words",
    'introduction' : "words",
    'qualification' : "words",
    'rapport' : "words"
}

answer = raw_input("Pick from these approaches: introduction, qualification, or rapport:")

while not answer in attraction.keys():
    answer = raw_input("You didn't choose one of the choices, type in the choice you want again:")

print attraction[answer]
```

Comment: you don't even need to use `.keys()`. By definition a dictionary iterates over it's keys - so you can simply use `while not answer in attraction:`

Comment: And that's what I get for not actually running the code in my answer.

Comment: @PeterWood Note that the in-loop `raw_input`s have a different prompt than the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
while True:
    answer = raw_input("Pick from these approaches: introduction, qualification, or rapport:")
    if answer == "approach" or answer == "introduction" or answer == "qualification" or answer == "rapport":
        break
```